# cvErode Error- Unknown Array Type

Tags: opencv

I am trying to perform an erosion of a JPEG image after converting the image to YCrCb image space. Using the following code

```
 YCrCbMin.val[0] = 0;
 YCrCbMin.val[1] = 131;
 YCrCbMin.val[2] = 80;

 YCrCbMax.val[0] = 255;
 YCrCbMax.val[1] = 185;
 YCrCbMax.val[2] = 135;

 imshow("img",Img);// Img is the JPEG image I load off the disk. 
 waitKey(0);

 Mat YCrCbImg;
 cvtColor(Img, YCrCbImg, CV_BGR2YCrCb);

 Mat erodedImg;
 inRange(YCrCbImg, YCrCbMin, YCrCbMax, erodedImg);

 Mat InterMediateImg     = YCrCbImg;
 IplConvKernel* element  = new IplConvKernel();

 element->nCols      = 12;   element->nRows      = 12;   element->anchorX    = 6;    element->anchorY    = 6;

  cvErode(&erodedImg, &InterMediateImg, element, 1);
  element->nCols      = 6;    element->nRows      = 6;    element->anchorX    = 3;    element->anchorY    = 3;
  cvDilate(&InterMediateImg, &erodedImg, element, 2);
```

On the first erosion, I get the following error as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Error Image]

I have used the following image as input

[image: index.jpg]

What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears probably when you call `cvErode` and `cvDilate`. You are mixing the C and C++ interface. So, for example, in

`cvErode(&erodedImg, &InterMediateImg, element, 1);`

`erodedImg` and `InterMediateImg` are of type `cv::Mat` when they should be of type `cvMat`. The same thing for `cvDilate`.

You can either use the new interface:

[cv::erode](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html#cv-erode)

```
void erode(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, const Mat& element, Point anchor=Point(-1, -1), int iterations=1, int borderType=BORDER_CONSTANT, const Scalar& borderValue=morphologyDefaultBorderValue())
```

and

[cv::dilate](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html#cv-dilate)

```
void dilate(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, const Mat& element, Point anchor=Point(-1, -1), int iterations=1, int borderType=BORDER_CONSTANT, const Scalar& borderValue=morphologyDefaultBorderValue())
```

or convert from `cv::Mat` to `cvMat`  [(link to cheatsheet)](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/c++_cheatsheet.html):

`CvMat cvmat = img; // convert cv::Mat -> CvMat`

Also notice that when you call those functions, the destination matrix is not empty and probably does not have the same type as the source matrix so there is a chance you will run in an error there too if I am not mistaken.

[Nice erosion and dilation tutorial in OpenCV 2.4.2](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html)